# AppleScript: Activate all mail rules with "sort: " in their name

Tags: macos, applescript, mail.app, mail-rules

I would like an AppleScript to activate all rules that have the string `"sort: "` in their names.

As far as I know this is how to enable a mail rule:

```
tell application "Mail" to set enabled of rule "sort: foo bar" to true
```

1. How do I get the names of all mail rules?
2. How do I filter these names for containing the string `"sort: "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple one-liner:
`tell application "Mail" to set enabled of rules whose name starts with "sort: " to true`

You don’t even need to `get` all those rules or their names; however if you want to do so it’s just as straightforward:
`tell application "Mail" to get name of rules whose name starts with "sort: "`

Note: your example *starts with* `sort:` but you asked about strings *containing* that string. If that is what you want then swap `contains` for `starts with` in the code I provided.